# Mysql range partition with range select

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I couldn't find an example like mine, so here's the thing:

I have a big data set that I need to aggregate on top of.

We're talking about ~ %500M rows with a date field ranging from 2y ago until now.
My first instinct was to partition the table by this field (creating a partition on the date field), which leaves roughly 20M rows per partition.

Then I have indexes on the other fields I will aggregate/group by.

Here's my table definition (simplified for brevity sake):

```
create table t1(
date_field datetime not null,
additional_id int not null,
category_id int not null,
value_field1 double,
value_field2 double,
primary key(additional_id,date_field)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB 
PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(date_field)*100 + MONTH(date_field)) (
PARTITION p_201411  VALUES LESS THAN (201411),
PARTITION p_201412  VALUES LESS THAN (201412),

#all the partitions until the current month...

PARTITION p_201610  VALUES LESS THAN (201610),
PARTITION p_201611  VALUES LESS THAN (201610),
PARTITION p_catchall VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );
```

If I execute a query that gets a date directly, only the partition for the month is used, based on the output of  **explain partitions** on top of a query such as the following one:

```
select value_field1 where additional_id=x and date_field='2014-11-05'
```

However, if I use a date range (even if inside the same partition), all partitions are scanned

```
select value_field1 where additional_id=x and date_field> '2014-11-05' and date_field <'2014-11-10'
```

(Same result if I use between).

What am I missing here? Is this really the right way to partition this table?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  Do not use complex expressions for `PARTITION BY RANGE`.

Long answer:  (Aside from criticizing the implementation of `BY RANGE` with range queries.)

Instead, do this:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(date_field)) (
PARTITION p_201411  VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2014-11-01')),
...
PARTITION p_catchall VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE );  -- unchanged
```

Newer versions of MySQL have slightly more friendly expressions you can use.

If this is your typical query:

```
additional_id=x and date_field> '2014-11-05'
                and date_field <'2014-11-10'
```

then partitioning is *no faster* than the equivalent non-partitioned table.  You even have the perfect index for the non-partitioned version.

If, on the other hand, you are `DROPping` old partitions when they 'expire', the `PARTITIONing` is excellent.

25 partitions is good.

[*More discussion*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/) .

A side note:  `additional_id int` is limited to 2 billion, so you are 1/4 of the way to overflowing.  `INT UNSIGNED` would get you to 4 billion; you might consider an `ALTER`.  (Of course, I don't know whether `additional_id` is unique in this table; so maybe it is not an issue.)

Comment: Thanks man! The additional_id was just an example of other fields, not really representative or the real table itself.

I changed the partitioning to using the to_days and the right partitions are targeted in the range query. Thanks.

I'm curious about your sentence "Aside from criticizing the implementation of BY RANGE with range queries". Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: That was a jab at MySQL developers who made so many severe restrictions on what can go into partition expressions.  It was not pointed at you.